# Mirror repositories on web development server

Tags: git, jenkins, server, gogs

As I read on git documentation bare repositories are good for sharing and non-bare repositories are good for developing.
I'm setting up a development server which should provide SCM, Jenkins, and serve webpages to do some manual testing.
To provide SCM I use [GOGS](http://gogs.io/) which creates bare repos to share between developers, I need that these bare repos somehow get hardlinked to non-bare repos on the apache folder (usually `/var/www/http/`) and mimic all the changes on the bare repo automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, create a bash(run it in cron job every 5 minutes) script and clone specific branch to you local apache folder (`git clone /path/to/your/local/bare/repo`).

Comment: I considered cloning the whole repo, but it seemed pretty inefficient, one of the reasons to use git is to minimize traffic and moving data.

Comment: You can trigger the cloning when a specific event happens using git hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> provide SCM I use GOGS which creates bare repos to share between developers, I need that these bare repos somehow get hardlinked to non-bare repos on the Apache folder (usually `/var/www/http/`)

That is generally done by a post-receive hook set in your bare repo managed by GOGS.
That script would be:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/var/www/http/ checkout -f
```

Any commit pushed to those bare repo will be visible in your web site.

Answer (score 1):

To make a non-bare repo, `git clone` the bare repo into the desired location.

As an aside, I would not recommend developing in the same location that is used for deployment.  It eventually constrains you in really undesirable ways.  Instead, build a small script that makes your "deployment bundle", a tgz or zip file that contains the items that need to be unpacked in your web server.